# How can I find (programmatically) which fields have been edited on a piece of content?

Tags: 7, entities

I want to have a computed field pull in the name and content of a field after it has been edited. I would also like the computed field to contain the content that was edited before edit (if that makes sense?). So what code do I need to find which field has been edited?

I also found this in the node_form drupal api:

```
// Changed must be sent to the client, for later overwrite error checking.
$form['changed'] = array(
  '#type' => 'hidden', 
  '#default_value' => isset($node->changed) ? $node->changed : NULL,
);
```

Is there a way I access this 'changed' value to check if a piece of content has been changed?

p.s. I am new to drupal and php, so stating your answer in simpler terms with more explination is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the node form submit, you can call `node_load($node->nid, NULL, TRUE)` for Drupal to retrieve the original about-to-be-overwritten node, allowing you to walk the list of fields, and compare them.

I would use `sha1sum(serialize($field))` to compare them, as that makes it easy to do regardless of field type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have a couple questions (I am new to drupal and php (read:student)). When you say "node form submit", is that a reference to the drupal api node_form? And if I call this function in the computed field do I need to instantiate the $node variable or the $field variable. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you know about hooks, then you need to implement a small custom module and use [`hook_form_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to alter the node form and insert custom submit handler like so `$form['#submit'][] = 'my_custom_submit_func';`. And write a function named `my_custom_submit_func` and in that function do the node_load and compare with the values in `$form_submit`. [Here's](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) the Form API page, very useful

Answer (score 0):

If you can use hook_node_presave, you have the handy property $node->original

https://api.drupal.org/comment/24933#comment-24933

Which saves you making an additional node_load

Comment: Hello and welcome :) Could you please provide code snippet or a bit more detailed explanation, to keep your answer useful in case your link goes down?

Comment: This doesn't work for all fields. Many have different structures in $node->original and $node. Many also have different structures when empty than when populated.